# using openstreet maps with marker and polylines with javascript

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

Guys i am complete newbie in using openstreetmaps .i know how to use google and bing maps api.
my requirement is to create a sample map with just some markers to locate and draw poly lines between them.i have read the api but couldnt find it how to use.this is used in  a commercial application.i need pointers and sample code.please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at either openlayers (what OSM use on their pages):

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/

Or Cloudmades new http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/ api

both of these can show open street map data

Comment: Thanks sry for taking epic time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this. you can do it very easily with openstreetmap.org , Use this following API 
http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you use a pre-rendered KML input file.  this example shows you how to do that on OSM:

http://maps.burningsilicon.net

place a link to your KML file on the bottom textbox.

you might want to check out PHP KML parser examples, if you want to create files on the fly from a MySQL database (or from a csv-style textfile).